# hide tab when no content & load content after onclick tab

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tabs

I have built a jquery tab that shows or hides the tab button if its content is empty or not.

Now, because of the pageload, I would like to only load the content when someone clicks on the tab button.

This is the code to check if there is content or not, and hide the tab if empty:

```
$j(function() {
    if ($j.trim( $j("#CONTENTDIV").html()) == "") {
        $j("li#TABBUTTON").hide();
    }
});
```

How do I make this load the content when clicked, but hide the tab button if it has no content?

Comment: If the tab is hidden, how can it be clicked to load content?

Comment: Than it keeps hidden because it has no content. I would like to have the tabs that have content visible, but load its content with an onclick event or something. Is this possible?

Comment: The only way to do that is to load all of the content up-front, preferably before initializing the tabs.

Comment: I was afraid youd say that. Any other ideas to have dynamic tab buttons, but loading the content after clicked? The content of the tab is just too large to load at once

Comment: If you don't know what the content is until you load it, you have to load it to find out if it has content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delay loading the contents of the tab until it is clicked, then you cannot know (prior to clicking) whether or not the tab should be shown (has content) or not (has none).

Philosophically, you could create a lightweight, AJAX function that requests an (essentially) empty page that simply asks for whether there is any value in a database field and simply return true if there is any content -- not the whole page. Then, on click, you could retrieve the contents.

**Edit**: This assumes, of course, that you can detect `some value` without retrieving the whole page.

Even if the request for the resources has to retrieve the whole amount, I believe the server should be able to access the resources more quickly than it would take to deliver the content to the user -- particularly if the resources reside on the same server that is doing the checking. Regardless, since it is being done in AJAX, you can keep the tabs hidden and show them (`$("#myTabID").show()`)as the lightweight, AJAX function discovers available content.

Comment: Sounds very interesting, but also very complicated. I'm currently thinking of a set of options in the backend to show or hide specific tabs per page. Than only make the the content visible once clicked on a tab. (It's only possible to click a tab when a tab is shown through the backend)

Comment: @SailesHardt; you should do whatever you think is best and what you're comfortable maintaining. If you have the time to experiment and learn about AJAX requests you'll find them hard to live without.